# Miscalculated Subway tile spacing What should I do?

Tags: kitchens, tile, backsplash

I miscalculated the spacing of subway tiles (*literally misstyped a number in my calculator*) I’m installing for my backsplash and ended up with a sliver left over at the top of my wall and under my cabinets.

What should I do? I’m thinking of leaving the under cabinet ones alone since I’m going to be installing deco strips which will hide it. But right near the ceiling there’s a 5/8” gap which means I’d have to cut 1/2” slivers to fill it in. I’m worried that will look bad.

Any thoughts from folks? Should I do it or is there an alternative solution?

[image]

Comment: 1/2" quarter round molding could also fill in the gap and will save you cutting tile, but might not be the aesthetic fit you're looking for.

Comment: A trim tile might be a more appropriate way to go - there are loads available. Then, when someone asks, you get to say "I meant for that to happen!". :)

Comment: I would probably grout it in then put a 1/4 round  that is so small by the time you space an “accent” strip there is really nothing left get a 1/4’ round that leaves the same size grout line +- and I would go with that.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to cut a few tile strips and tape them up there to see how it looks.

Answer (score 1):

Pity the tiles are laid: I'd have run full tiles down from the ceiling, and got rid of the cuts you put to line up with the top of the window architrave. You could have packed out the top of the architrave almost invisibly with timber and paint.

As it is, fit a small timber trim/coving, call it what you will and paint it as if it's part of the ceiling. Only you will notice it.